# Fake phone call

Tags: encryption, network, malware, android, gmail

I have a problem, getting call from known numbers and when he lifts it, no one is speaking from other side!
Well, the awkward part is, the call is from known numbers only, but if I ask the person calling back to them, they strangely answered that they have not called me on the day!
I am hoping someone used those numbers and called me fake, to fake me up!
1) I am getting calls from my family numbers
2) when i life, no one is talking
3)when i call back, Strangely they answered" I dint call you"

SOME ONE IS SUSPICIOUSLY USING MY CONTACTS AND CALLING ME FAKELY MISUSING MY CONTACTS, WITHOUT NOTICE OF PEOPLE OF MY CONTACT

Well, I have doubt that, how is it possible to make a call from A to B, without notice of A and this could make a misuse i future!

Please help me to find that guy and how he did this?

is it malware? trojan?

Answer (score 2):

Probably somebody is calling you with voIP phones... you can make it seem as if you are calling from any number or even make it appear as is "xxx bank" or whatever. So no biggies on that part. It is very popular nowadays to call people from voIP systems with fake caller info.

On your second question, being called from only known people... Look for a pattern, maybe only your co-workers are calling you? Or only class mates from a certain class? Than someone from office/class is messing with you. If not, you may some how get hacked and lost all your contacts...

Comment: Most VoIP operators do however limit the information in CallerID field to only match the customer's account number. (eg phone number that belong to the customer). Thus faking callerID on VoIP calls would only be possible by raw VoIP calls (from a sip:xxx@xxx.xx url to a sip:xxx@xxx.xx url). On PSTN calls it should be pretty complicated due to operator restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

If you always receive the calls from the very same person, then it might be a trojan on THEIR phone that calls you.

However, if theres calls from multiple persons, then it might be the thing that people call "pocket calls", basically, the phone sits in pocket along with keys, wallets, and other objects that push buttons and/or touch touchscreen which in many times result in that the latest called person is being called.

That will result in a "silent call". Note that even if the phone is screen locked, sometimes the objects manage to unlock the screenlock since screen locks often concist of simple movements like "push button, swipe right" or such.